# Magento 2.3.1 Fatal Error when overriding Helper in Magento Bundle module

Tags: magento2, helper, bundle

In order to override the function `getBundleOptions` from `magento2/vendor/magento/module-bundle/Helper/Catalog/Product/Configuration.php` i have implemented the following module:

**MySpace/MyModule3/etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Bundle\Helper\Catalog\Product\Configuration" type="MySpace\MyModule3\Helper\Bundle\Catalog\Product\Configuration\Configuration" />
</config>
```

**MySpace/MyModule3/Helper/Bundle/Catalog/Product/Configuration/Configuration.php**

```
<?php
namespace MySpace\MyModule3\Helper\Bundle\Catalog\Product\Configuration;
class Configuration extends Magento\Bundle\Helper\Catalog\Product\Configuration
{
    /**
     * Get bundled selections (slections-products collection)
     *
     * Returns array of options objects.
     * Each option object will contain array of selections objects
     *
     * @param ItemInterface $item
     * @return array
     */
    public function getBundleOptions(ItemInterface $item)
    {
        $options = [];
        $product = $item->getProduct();

        /** @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type $typeInstance */
        $typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();

        // get bundle options
        $optionsQuoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('bundle_option_ids');
        $bundleOptionsIds = $optionsQuoteItemOption
            ? $this->serializer->unserialize($optionsQuoteItemOption->getValue())
            : [];

        if ($bundleOptionsIds) {
            /** @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Option\Collection $optionsCollection */
            $optionsCollection = $typeInstance->getOptionsByIds($bundleOptionsIds, $product);

            // get and add bundle selections collection
            $selectionsQuoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('bundle_selection_ids');

            $bundleSelectionIds = $this->serializer->unserialize($selectionsQuoteItemOption->getValue());

            if (!empty($bundleSelectionIds)) {
                $selectionsCollection = $typeInstance->getSelectionsByIds($bundleSelectionIds, $product);

                $bundleOptions = $optionsCollection->appendSelections($selectionsCollection, true);
                foreach ($bundleOptions as $bundleOption) {
                    if ($bundleOption->getSelections()) {
                        $option = ['label' => $bundleOption->getTitle(), 'value' => []];

                        $bundleSelections = $bundleOption->getSelections();

                        foreach ($bundleSelections as $bundleSelection) {
                            $qty = $this->getSelectionQty($product, $bundleSelection->getSelectionId()) * 1;
                            if ($qty) {
                                $option['value'][] = $this->escaper->escapeHtml($bundleSelection->getName());
                                $option['has_html'] = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if ($option['value']) {
                            $options[] = $option;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```

However, the module is not working, and still returns the following:

```
Fatal error:  Class 'MySpace\MyModule3\Helper\Bundle\Catalog\Product\Configuration\Magento\Bundle\Helper\Catalog\Product\Configuration' not found in /data/web/magento2/app/code/MySpace/MyModule3/Helper/Bundle/Catalog/Product/Configuration/Configuration.php on line 3
```

Any ideas of how to correct for this error, and make the module work?

Comment: I think you forgot to add "\" before exdends class in "Configuration.php" file,
It should be "\Magento\Bundle\Helper\Catalog\Product\Configuration" insted of "Magento\Bundle\Helper\Catalog\Product\Configuration"

Comment: Hi @Kishor After adjusting it as indicated; i get the following error when compiling: 
Warning: Declaration of MySpace\MyModule3\Helper\Bundle\Catalog\Product\Configuration\Configuration::getBundleOptions(MySpace\MyModule3\Helper\Bundle  
  \Catalog\Product\Configuration\ItemInterface $item) should be compatible with Magento\Bundle\Helper\Catalog\Product\Configuration::getBundleOptions(M  
  agento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemInterface $item) in /data/web/magento2/app/code/MySpace/MyModule3/Helper/Bundle/Catalog/Product/Configuration/Configuration.php on line 65

Comment: Not sure but you need to add this 
"use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemInterface;" under the namespace line and run the "php bin/magento setup:di:compile" command.

Please check core file code to get more information.

Comment: The error is gone when compiling; now i get the following error on the screen: Notice: Undefined property: MySpace\MyModule3\Helper\Bundle\Catalog\Product\Configuration\Configuration\Interceptor::$serializer in /data/web/magento2/app/code/MySpace/MyModule3/Helper/Bundle/Catalog/Product/Configuration/Configuration.php on line 27

Answer (score 0):

In This File`MySpace/MyModule3/Helper/Bundle/Catalog/Product/Configuration/Configuration.php
Change definition to` class Configuration extends \Magento\Bundle\Helper\Catalog\Product\Configuration

Comment: Hi Diego. Thanks for your answer. I did it already. I also implemented “use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemInterface;" under the namespace line, as suggested by Kishor. Now i get the following error to see on the screen: Notice: Undefined property: MySpace\MyModule3\Helper\Bundle\Catalog\Product\Configuration\Configuration\Interceptor::$serializer in /data/web/magento2/app/code/MySpace/MyModule3/Helper/Bundle/Catalog/Product/Configuration/Configuration.php on line 27